# Agregar dos botones a JFrame de dibujo y almacenar luego el dibujo realizado

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Tengo el siguiente código para dibujar en un JFrame

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class VentanaDisposicionMesas extends JComponent implements ActionListener{

    static JFrame frmPrincipal;

    private Point inicioArrastre;
    private Point finArrastre;
    private ArrayList lineas = new ArrayList();

    JButton btnGuardar;
    JButton btnCerrar;

    JPanel pnlBotones;

    public VentanaDisposicionMesas() {
        super();
    
        metodoCargarPanel();
    
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { // cuando se presiona el mouse
                inicioArrastre = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { // cuando se deja de presionar el mouse
                finArrastre = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                Shape linea = crearLinea(inicioArrastre.x, inicioArrastre.y, finArrastre.x, finArrastre.y);
                lineas.add(linea);
                repaint();
            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { // cuando se esta arrastrando el mouse
                finArrastre = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                Shape linea = crearLinea(inicioArrastre.x, inicioArrastre.y, finArrastre.x, finArrastre.y);
                lineas.add(linea);
                inicioArrastre = new Point(finArrastre.x, finArrastre.y);
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (Object linea : lineas) { 
            g2.draw((Shape) linea);
        }
    }

    private Line2D.Float crearLinea(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        return new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame ventana = new JFrame("Ejemplo para la Disposición de Mesas");

        ventana.setSize(600, 400);
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ventana.add(new VentanaDisposicionMesas());
        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == btnCerrar){
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if (ae.getSource() == btnGuardar){
            ;
        }
    }

    private void metodoCargarPanel() {
        pnlBotones = new JPanel();
        pnlBotones.setBounds(0, 550, 400, 30);
        this.add(pnlBotones);
    
        btnCerrar = new JButton("Cerrar");
        btnCerrar.addActionListener(this);
        btnCerrar.setBounds(50, 15, 150, 15);
        pnlBotones.add(btnCerrar);
    
        btnGuardar = new JButton("Cerrar");
        btnGuardar.addActionListener(this);
        btnGuardar.setBounds(205, 15, 150, 15);
        pnlBotones.add(btnGuardar);
    }
}
```

Me funciona bien, pero ahora intento agregarle el panel con los dos botones, y no lo he conseguido de ninguna manera.

Lo he intentado agregando los botones a this.add(btnCerrar);
pero no funciona

he intentado hacer otro JFrame y agregar éste del dibujo al anterior, pero tampoco he podido

si lo intento agregar con el nombre del JFrame (ventana.add();) me da error

Estoy empezando con el tema de Java Swing, y no me entero muy bien, alguien puede iluminarme un poco el camino ?

por otra parte, sería posible guardar como imagen el dibujo realizado en el JFrame ?
Esa sería la función del botón Guardar

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estas agregando el panel de botones al marco, sino al componente (el de dibujo), los componentes si no mal recuerdo tienen FlowLayout por defecto, mientras que JFrame tiene BorderLayout. FlowLayout no mostrara los componentes si no tienen un tamaño definido.

Puedes aprovechar los lugares que te deja usar BorderLayout para esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

BorderLayout agrega a CENTER por defecto remplazando cualquier componente que se encuentre ahí y ocupando todo el espacio disponible mientras no hallan componentes a su alrededor, en otras palabras solo se puede agregar 1 componente en  cada lugar (de ahí los paneles anidados con BorderLayout)

Por ejemplo:

```
ventana.add(new VentanaDisposicionMesas2());
```

Pero el panel de botones lo estas agregando al componente...

```
this.add(pnlBotones);
```

1 - No se ve si no tiene un tamaño definido (efecto de FlowLayout).
2 - No creo que lo quieras agregar ahí ya que podrías pintar sobre los botones y saldrían en la imagen guardada.

El panel de botones debes agregarlo por ejemplo a NORTH pero debes especificarlo porque no es por defecto como CENTER.

Luego de cargar/crear el panel puedes agregarlo arriba con:

```
ventana.add(pnlBotones, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

---

Por otra parte está la de guardar lo dibujado en una imagen, esto se hace imprimiendo los gráficos del componente en un `BufferedImage` y utilizando `ImageIO.write` puedes escribir la imagen.

```
public void guardarImagenDeDisposiciones(File destino) {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
    
    BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
    
    Graphics2D g2 = buffered.createGraphics();
    printAll(g2);
    
    try {
        ImageIO.write(buffered, "png", destino);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que imprime el lugar dibujado, osea que el fondo es transparente con lineas rojas,
esto es porque estas pintando un componente desde 0, al igual que JButton tiene sus gráficos, tu estas creando los tuyos para el panel de dibujo, si quieres que sea sobre un fondo blanco solo has un fill de color blanco.

---

El código es el mismo pero lo distribuí en diferentes clases para no pelearme con variables estáticas, ya que había un conflicto en la creación del JFrame y el componente (método main estático y los componentes del panel botones) esta en vos implementarlo como quieras.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VentanaDisposicionesMesa ventana = new VentanaDisposicionesMesa();
    }
    
}

class VentanaDisposicionesMesa implements ActionListener {
    
    private JFrame frmDisposiciones;
    
    private CanvasDeDisposicion canvasDisposicion;
    private JPanel pnlBotones;
    
    private JButton btnGuardar;
    private JButton btnCerrar;
    
    public VentanaDisposicionesMesa() {
        frmDisposiciones = new JFrame("Ejemplo para la Disposición de Mesas");
        
        frmDisposiciones.setSize(600, 400);
        frmDisposiciones.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frmDisposiciones.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        metodoCargarPanel();
        frmDisposiciones.add(pnlBotones, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        frmDisposiciones.add(canvasDisposicion = new CanvasDeDisposicion()); // CENTER
        
        frmDisposiciones.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private void metodoCargarPanel() {
        pnlBotones = new JPanel();
        pnlBotones.setBounds(0, 550, 400, 30);
    
        btnCerrar = new JButton("Cerrar");
        btnCerrar.addActionListener(this);
        btnCerrar.setBounds(50, 15, 150, 15);
        pnlBotones.add(btnCerrar);
    
        btnGuardar = new JButton("Guardar");
        btnGuardar.addActionListener(this);
        btnGuardar.setBounds(205, 15, 150, 15);
        pnlBotones.add(btnGuardar);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == btnCerrar){
            canvasDisposicion.setVisible(false);
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == btnGuardar) {
            File file = new File("/home/pablo/Escritorio/imagen.png");
            canvasDisposicion.guardarImagenDeDisposiciones(file);
        }
    }
    
}

class CanvasDeDisposicion extends JComponent {
    
    private Point inicioArrastre;
    private Point finArrastre;
    
    private ArrayList<Shape> lineas = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public CanvasDeDisposicion() {
        super();
        
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { // cuando se presiona el mouse
                inicioArrastre = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { // cuando se deja de presionar el mouse
                finArrastre = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                
                Shape linea = crearLinea(inicioArrastre.x, inicioArrastre.y, finArrastre.x, finArrastre.y);
                lineas.add(linea);
                
                repaint();
            }
            
        });
        
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { // cuando se esta arrastrando el mouse
                finArrastre = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                
                Shape linea = crearLinea(inicioArrastre.x, inicioArrastre.y, finArrastre.x, finArrastre.y);
                lineas.add(linea);
                
                inicioArrastre = new Point(finArrastre.x, finArrastre.y);
                
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        
        for (Object linea : lineas) { 
            g2.draw((Shape) linea);
        }
    }
    
    private Line2D.Float crearLinea(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        return new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
    
    public void guardarImagenDeDisposiciones(File destino) {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
        
        BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
        
        Graphics2D g2 = buffered.createGraphics();
        printAll(g2);
        
        try {
            ImageIO.write(buffered, "png", destino);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda

Comment: Pues muchísimas gracias @JFrame, sólo con tus explicaciones me has iluminado la práctica oscuridad que tenía. No me está resultando sencillo el tema JFrame, JPanel y Layout. Me lío, los mezclo y los confundo. Me pongo a estudiar tu respuesta. Lo dicho, muchísimas gracias.